# Buscar string em código html

Tags: c#, html, html5

Preciso de ajuda para o seguinte:

_Adicionar varios arquivos ( extensão .htm ), aprox 20 arquivos.
_Analizar e encontrar nos 20 arquivos uma string determinada no código HTML ( longitude máxima de da string é de 20 caracteres).

Pensava realizar em html com Javascript pra realizar isso ou preferem outra linguagem como C#? Observação: meu conhecimento de programação é baixo.
Favor sua ajuda e orientação! Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Coloque o código que você já tentou fazer. Isso ajuda a entender o problema que você está tendo.

Comment: Então.... eu ainda não comecei a realizar ele, por isso que eu queria orientação se realizar com javascript ou C#. Uma vez definido isso eu iria subir meus códigos.

Comment: Então sugiro melhorar o texto da pergunta porque não dá pra entender qual é essa orientação que você quer.

Comment: aparentemente, não faz sentido usar javascript pois ele roda no navegador, e você "tem 20 arquivos" para analisar. Você pode usar C# sim, e recomendo adicionar o `HtmlAgilityPack` que ajuda muito. Poréeeeeem, se são só esses 20 arquivos, porque não usa o Notepad++ e busca o que precisa nesses arquivos ?!

Comment: A razão de não utilizar Notepad++ é porque os usuários ( aprox 10 ) são leigos.
Tipo preciso algo que praticamente só selecionen o diretório a ser analizado e pronto.

Answer (score 0):

C# é uma  linguagem  de programação que roda do lado do servidor muito mais capaz de ler e escrever arquivos, não possui capacidade de fazer alterações no lado do cliente, para fazer leitura de arquivos em  C# pode usar a bibiliteca [System.IO.File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx)

Javascript é hoje possui um termo "variavel" quanto sua realtividade em  programação pois antigamente era usado apenas como script que rodava no lado cliente mas hoje vai alem disso, pode ler arquivos e criar arquivos do lado cliente utilizando novas tecnologias como  html5, e também  há sua versão no  servidor que é o node.js que é utilizado como linguagem de  programação que faz basicamente o mesmo que o C#

```
1. -Agora para seu caso eu ainda usaria C# por poder ler os arquivos
no servidor, e atravez de url

2. - Javascript - lado cliente ainda há umas  limitações e
provavelmente você vai econtar algumas  barreiras para fazer isso

3. - A não ser que você esta usando um servidor node.js e vá fazer a
leitura com a linguagem  Javascript no servidor em  fim
```

veja qual das opições será mais pratica para seu uso.

Ainda há uma  possibilidade de fazer uma pagina dinamica utilizando c# para ler os arquivos e javascript para trazer para o lado do cliente veja como  em  [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Marcos, muito obrigado pela explicação.
Eu nunca programei em C# na minha vida, mais quero me aventurar nisso, apesar não ter ideia de nada sobre a linguagem.
é muito complexo?

Comment: @RodrigoHackzExploitz nada é complexo basta se dedicar c# em  comparação a c e C++ poussui uma syntax bem  mais limpa, com o tempo  você também se acostuma a trabalhar com objetos eu  comecei a programar em c#  a uns 4 meses antes eu so trabalhava com php  agora c# já se parece bem facil para mim, creio que você aprenderá com facilidade desde que se esforce e foque

Answer (score 0):

C# é a maneira mais rapida para ler os 20 arquivos e gerar o seu resultado.
Exemplo em C#:

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"c:\htmls\html1.html");
string line;
line = file.ReadToEnd();
string[] x = line.Split(' ');

foreach (var item in x)
{
   if(item.Length == 20)
   {
   //faca alguma coisa
   }          
}
```

Comment: split em `' '` ?? vai zonear tudo em

Comment: eu criei um exemplo como base